# Fullcalendar remove event Ajax/PHP

Tags: php, ajax, fullcalendar

I am trying to use **removeEvent** method in my calendar and send data in ajax to delete the event from my database.

```
eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
    $.ajax({
       url: 'calendar/remove_event.php',
       data: 'id=' + event.id,
       type: "POST",
       success: function () {
          $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', calEvent._id);
       }
   });
},
```

and my PHP:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];

$ligacao = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "mydatabase");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Can't connect to database: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql = "delete from events WHERE id= '$id'";
$resultado = mysqli_query($ligacao, $sql);
mysqli_close($ligacao);
```

When i click the event, it is removed from the calendar but if i refresh the page it's there again, because it wasn't removed from the database.
Here is the documentation for these methods (removeEvent and eventClick):

Here is full calendar eventClick.

1. [Reference 1](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/eventClick/)
2. [Reference 2](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/removeEvents/)

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that, i edited the question :)

Comment: You need to check it from database also at the time of page load

Answer (score 0):

Check the php code..

Maybe because this line

```
$sql = "delete from events WHERE id= '$id'";
```

Just change to this

```
$sql = "delete from events WHERE id='".$id."'";
```

And check the ajax too, you can use Developer Tools in chrome (Network tab) to see the network log or add this code to your ajax and see on the Console

```
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log(jqXHR);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You did a mistake in your `eventClick` function : `event` isn't defined. Try to remplace it with the correct variable name (`calEvent`).

Moreover, the `_id` property doesn't exist in the [Event object](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/), so in your `removeEvents` remplace it with `id`.

```
eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
    $.ajax({
       url: 'calendar/remove_event.php',
       data: 'id=' + calEvent.id,
       type: "POST",
       success: function () {
          $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', calEvent.id);
       }
   });
},
```

Comment: i tried with calEvent already, but that just deletes all the events on the calendar, and not just the one i clicked.

Comment: Do you check that all your events had different ids ? If they have the same, the libary think that it's a repeating event and it delete all occurence.

Comment: they do have different id's

Comment: And is it working if you do `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', calEvent);` directly ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the id just like this.

```
eventClick: function( event, jsEvent, view ) { }
```

Instead of.

```
eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) { }
```

and next you can access to the element id just with the property of the event.

```
event.id
```

After this short explanation the final code would be like this.

```
eventClick: function( event, jsEvent, view ) {
$.ajax({
   url: 'calendar/remove_event.php',
   data: 'id=' + event.id,
   type: "POST",
   success: function () {
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', calEvent._id);
   }
 });
},
```

With this fix probably your delete method in php works fine.

References: http://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/eventClick/

Thnks.